# complex db2/sql query with time-sampling, group, map, join and csv export

Tags: join, db2, time-series, ibm-cloud, export-to-csv

I have data in a table (named: TESTING) on a dashDB2 on IBM bluemix (Db2 Warehouse on Cloud) which is looking like this:

```
ID     TIMESTAMP                  NAME     VALUE
abc    2017-12-21 19:55:38.762    test1    123
abc    2017-12-21 19:55:42.762    test2    456
abc    2017-12-21 19:57:38.762    test1    789
abc    2017-12-21 19:58:38.762    test3    345
def    2017-12-21 19:59:38.762    test1    678
```

I am looking for a query that:

1. samples the data (for each NAME) to a given timeformat (ex. to a 1 minute based timestamp)
2. VALUES in same timerange (in same minute) should be averaged, empty times should be NULL

for 1. and 2. something like (only for one NAME working):

```
    with dummy(temporaer) as (
      select TIMESTAMP('2017-12-01') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
      union all
      select temporaer + 1 MINUTES from dummy where temporaer < TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01')
    )
    select temporaer, avg(VALUE) as test1 from dummy
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TESTING ON temporaer=date_trunc('minute', TIMESTAMP) and ID='abc' and NAME='test1'
    group by temporaer
    ORDER BY temporaer ASC;
```

3. join all different NAMES column-wise to a matrix, like:

   ```
   TIMESTAMP               test1    test2    test3
   2017-12-01 00:00:00     null     null     null
   ...
   2017-12-21 19:55:00     123      456      null
   2017-12-21 19:56:00     null     null     null
   2017-12-21 19:57:00     789      null     null
   2017-12-21 19:58:00     678      null     345
   ...
   2018-01-31 23:59:00     null     null     null
   ```
4. the query result should be exportet as a csv. or given back as csv-string

Does anybody know how this could be done in one query or in a simple and fast way? Or is it necessary to save the data in another tabe-format - can you give me a hint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 comma separated output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output).  Actually getting "CSV" output isn't the responsibility of a query, it's the responsibility of the system running the query.  `LISTAGG` is sortof going to hurt you here, in that it returns a string, so you'd need to strip out the surrounding quote marks

Comment: "listagg" is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CROSS JOIN was defenitly a nice hint. Also I was not able to implement the following LEFT JOIN like you suggested, I found a workaround, which - I am sure - still keeps room for improvement but at this moment is acceptable for me (timesaving about factor 30 compared to my first query solution). Here the actual code:

```
WITH
    -- generate a range of times from date to date in defined steps:
    TimeRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd) AS (SELECT a, a + 1 MINUTE
                                                            FROM (VALUES(TIMESTAMP('2017-12-19'))) D(a)
                                                            UNION ALL
                                                            SELECT rangeEnd, rangeEnd + 1 MINUTE
                                                            FROM TimeRange
                                                            WHERE rangeEnd < TIMESTAMP('2017-12-24')),

    -- get all distinct names in table:
    Header(names) AS (SELECT DISTINCT name
                                     FROM FIELDTEST
                                     WHERE ID = '7b9bbe44d45d8f2ac324849a4951da54'
                                                   AND REGEXP_LIKE(VALUE, '^\s*\d+(\.\d*)?\s*$') 
                                                   AND timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2017-12-19')
                                                   AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP('2017-12-24')),

    -- select data (names, values without stringvalues) from table dedicated by timestamp to bigger timeinterval (here minutes):
    rawData(time, names, values) AS (SELECT date_trunc('minute', TIMESTAMP), NAME, VALUE
                                     FROM FIELDTEST
                                     WHERE ID = '7b9bbe44d45d8f2ac324849a4951da54'
                                        AND REGEXP_LIKE(VALUE, '^\s*\d+(\.\d*)?\s*$')),

    -- I'm assuming the (id, name) tuple is unique, which means we don't need to repeat the regex later
    Data(rangeStart, name, averaged) AS (SELECT TimeRange.rangeStart, Header.names, COALESCE(AVG(rawData.values), -9999)
                                         FROM TimeRange
                                         CROSS JOIN Header
                                         LEFT JOIN rawData
                                            ON rawData.names = Header.names
                                                AND rawData.time = TimeRange.rangeStart
                                         GROUP BY TimeRange.rangeStart, Header.names),

    test(time, names, avgvalues) AS (SELECT Data.rangeStart,
                                            LISTAGG(Data.name,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY name),
                                            LISTAGG(Data.averaged,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY name)
                                    FROM Data
                                    GROUP BY Data.rangeStart)

-- build my own delimited export-string:
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(REPLACE(time,'.',':'),1,19),';'), REPLACE(CAST(avgvalues AS VARCHAR(3980)),'-9999',''))
FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(CAST('TIME;' AS VARCHAR(5)), CAST(LISTAGG(names,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY names) AS VARCHAR(3980)))
FROM Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a code snipped that does the job, but needs very long time:

```
WITH
    -- get all distinct names in table:
    header(names) AS (SELECT DiSTINCT name
                      FROM FIELDTEST
                      WHERE ID='7b9bbe44d45d8f2ac324849a4951da54' AND REGEXP_LIKE(trim(VALUE),'^\d+(\.\d*)?$') AND DATE(TIMESTAMP)>='2017-12-19' AND DATE(TIMESTAMP)<'2017-12-24'),

    -- select data (names, values without stringvalues) from table dedicated by timestamp to bigger timeinterval (here minutes):
    dummie(time, names, values) AS (SELECT date_trunc('minute', TIMESTAMP), NAME, VALUE
                                    FROM FIELDTEST
                                    WHERE ID='7b9bbe44d45d8f2ac324849a4951da54' AND REGEXP_LIKE(trim(VALUE),'^\d+(\.\d*)?$')),

    -- generate a range of times from date to date in defined steps:
    dummy(time, rangeEnd) AS (SELECT a, a + 1 MINUTE
                                           FROM (VALUES(TIMESTAMP('2017-12-19'))) D(a)
                                           UNION ALL
                                           SELECT rangeEnd, rangeEnd + 1 MINUTE
                                           FROM dummy
                                           WHERE rangeEnd < TIMESTAMP('2017-12-24')),

    -- add each name (from header) to each time/row (in dummy):
    dumpy(time, names) AS (SELECT Dummy.time, Header.names
                                FROM Dummy
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Header
                                ON Dummy.time IS NOT NULL),

    -- averages values by name and timeinterval and sorts result to dummy:
    dummj(time, names, avgvalues) AS (SELECT Dummy.time, Dummie.names, AVG(Dummie.values)
                                      FROM Dummy
                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN Dummie
                                      ON Dummie.time = Dummy.time
                                      GROUP BY Dummie.names, Dummy.time),

    -- joins the averages (by time, name) values to the times and names in dumpy (on empty value use -9999):
    testo(time, names, avgvalues) AS (SELECT Dumpy.time, Dumpy.names, COALESCE(Dummj.avgvalues,-9999)
                                    FROM Dumpy
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Dummj
                                    ON Dummj.time = Dumpy.time AND Dummj.names = Dumpy.names),

    -- converts the high amount of rows to less rows with delimited strings:
    test(time, names, avgvalues) AS (SELECT time, LISTAGG(names,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY names), LISTAGG(avgvalues,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY names)
                                     FROM Testo
                                     GROUP BY time)

SELECT* FROM test ORDER BY time ASC, names ASC;
```

The performance problem is in the "testo" subquery. Does anybody have an idea what is the failure here or know how to improve the query?

Comment: perhaps the reason is that the "testo" join-subquery is based on two other join-subqueries...?!? but what is the problem on that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem I see is that you keep using functions on columns, but that shouldn't be too big a drain if `id` is reasonably unique.  If this query is very common, it may also be worth it to permanently build and index the range table.  Hmm, you probably need several indices (starting with `FieldTest.id`), but you might also try this version:

```
-- let's name things properly, too, to keep them straight.
WITH
    -- generate a range of times from date to date in defined steps:
   Range (rangeStart, rangeEnd) AS (SELECT a, a + 1 MINUTE
                                    FROM (VALUES(TIMESTAMP('2017-12-19'))) D(a)
                                    UNION ALL
                                    SELECT rangeEnd, rangeEnd + 1 MINUTE
                                    FROM Range
                                    WHERE rangeEnd < TIMESTAMP('2017-12-24')),
    -- get all distinct names in table:
    Header(names) AS (SELECT DISTINCT name
                      FROM FieldTest
                      WHERE ID = '7b9bbe44d45d8f2ac324849a4951da54' 
                            -- just make the white space check part of the regex
                            AND REGEXP_LIKE(VALUE, '^\s*\d+(\.\d*)?\s*$') 
                            AND timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2017-12-19')
                            AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP('2017-12-24')),
    -- I'm assuming the (id, name) tuple is unique, which means we don't need to repeat the regex later
    Data (rangeStart, name, averaged) AS (SELECT Range.rangeStart, Header.names, COALESCE(AVG(FieldTest.value), -9999)
                                          FROM Range
                                          CROSS JOIN Header
                                          LEFT JOIN FieldTest
                                                 ON FieldTest.id = '7b9bbe44d45d8f2ac324849a4951da54'
                                                    AND FieldTest.names = Header.names
                                                    AND FieldTest.timestamp >= Range.rangeStart
                                                    AND FieldTest.timestamp < Range.rangeEnd
                                          GROUP BY Range.rangeStart, Header.names),
-- I can't recall if DB2 allows using the new column name this way, you may need to wrap this again
SELECT rangeStart, 
               -- converts the high amount of rows to less rows with delimited strings:
       LISTAGG(names,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY names) AS names, 
       LISTAGG(avgvalues,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY names)
GROUP BY rangeStart
ORDER BY rangeStart, names
```

(not tested)